# Pass Data Via Object In Laravel Vue Form

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js

I want To Pass Vue Form data via object, But when I pass data it throws error

> SyntaxError: E:...\js\frontend\Profile.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (251:4)

Here Is My Code

```
export default {
    props : [
        'user'
    ],
    methods : {
        profile() {
            axios
                .put(`/web/me`, {
                    user.firstName : this.user.firstName,
                    user.lastName  : this.user.lastName,
                    profile.code   : this.user.profile.code,
                })
                .then((e) => {
                    window.location.href = '/profile';
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    this.errors    = e.response.data.errors;

                })
        },
    }
}
```

I could not find a way to sent It. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your json file is incorrect, please remove the comma from last of `profile.code : this.user.profile.code,`

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh already tried but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON structure is incorrect. You can't use "." as a key in the JSON structure.
if user is an object:
you can use like this code:

```
export default {
        props : [
            'user'
        ],
        methods : {
            profile() {
                var data = {};
                data[user.firstName] = this.user.firstName;
                data[user.lastName] = this.user.lastName;
                data[profile.code] = this.user.profile.code;
                axios
                    .put(`/web/me`, data)
                    .then((e) => {
                        window.location.href = '/profile';
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        this.errors    = e.response.data.errors;

                    })
            },
        }
    }
```

user is not an object:

```
export default {
        props : [
            'user'
        ],
        methods : {
            profile() {
                var data = {
                  'user': {
                    'firstName': this.user.firstName,
                    'lastName': this.user.lastName,
                  },
                  'profile': {
                    'code': this.user.profile.code
                  }
                };
                axios
                    .put(`/web/me`, data)
                    .then((e) => {
                        window.location.href = '/profile';
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        this.errors    = e.response.data.errors;

                    })
            },
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there not any way to bind data in key value format in Json?

Comment: The above code throws error `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: user is not defined"`

Comment: Already did but throws error `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstName' of undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of your object key to be without a dot.

```
user.firstName : this.user.firstName
```

The previous is not a proper object key. You need to change it to the following:

```
userFirstName : this.user.firstName
```

Comment: No Sir I did not want this.